# Maximal entropy of joint distribution of 2 independent random variables given probability of equality

Tags: optimization, information-theory, entropy

Consider 2 **INDEPENDENT** random variables $X$ and $Y$ with values in $A=\{0, 1, \ldots, q-1\}$. Suppose that $P(X=Y)$ is equal to some constant $\varepsilon$.

1. What is the maximal entropy $H(X, Y)$?
2. At which distribution this maximum is attained?

My hypothesis is that the distribution $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=\alpha$, $P(X=k)=P(Y=k)=(1-\alpha) / (q - 1)$, $k=1,\ldots,q-1$ gives the optimal answer, where $\alpha$ is calculated from equation $\alpha^2+(1-\alpha)^2/(q-1)=\varepsilon$. Using the standard method of Lagrange multipliers and some hacks I've managed to prove that for $\varepsilon>1/q$ the optimal distribution have the following form 
$P(X=i)=P(Y=i)=p_1$ for $i=0, \ldots, l-1$ and $P(X=i)=P(Y=i)=p_2$ for $k=l,\ldots,q-1$. Computer simulations show that you can always pick $l=1$.

Comment: This is an interesting question (at least, I think it is), but you should write down what you've tried; other users are unlikely to help you if you don't.

Comment: It seems like a known fact. I've hoped that somebody will give me a link to some article or book.

Comment: How do you determine $l$ for the case that you’ve proved?

Comment: I proved that it is true for some $l$, but I don't know how to determine it.

Comment: Mea culpa on misreading the Q. Deleted the ans.